# According to Meinong's theory, is it false that all circles are not square?

Tags: truth

According to Meinong's theory, "square circles are circles" is a true statement.

Does it mean that "circles include square circles" is true, so **is it false that all circles are not square?**

Comment: You cannot express Meinongian theories by basic means of classical predicate logic, quantification works differently there. "Square circles are circles" does not contradict "all circles are not square" when properly interpreted, because of the difference between existence and subsistence or exemplification and encoding, or a similar distinction that a Meinongian uses when limiting the scope of quantification.